# How to insert enter within the text of html code?

Tags: html

I am writing up a resume, and the enter, space, and other characters do not show up. It's a poorly coded website. Is there a way to include enter key without accessing the source of the html code, or including html elements? If I insert **< br >** element, it shows up as     **& lt; br &gt ;&#10**

Comment: Probably not, if it is really that poorly coded. When you say that the space character is not showing up, do you mean that when you use many spaces that they show up as just one?

Comment: Yes you're right @wedstrom. It shows up as a single space character

Comment: The title here is a bit misleading, as it suggests the question is about white-space within HTML code, but apparently there is no access to code.

Answer (score 0):

HTML ignores extra white-space.  Use `<br />` in place of Enter, and `&nbsp;` for the space character.

You can also use the `<pre>` tag.  Any text inside this tag will show up as formatted, including spaces and the enter key.

However, since you are using a third-party website here, Wedstrom is right that the above shouldn't work.  There is no way for you to change or add HTML code on another party's site, and there shouldn't be.  Try to find a way to write up your resume using the functionality that is readily provided for you (or use your own text editor...).

Comment: Same with <pre> tags. Anytime I enter the '<' character it shows up as entity in the page.

Comment: Is that also the case with `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Yes if I insert the html entity codes, it just turns up without any change

Answer (score 0):

Chava G's suggestion might work, but it really shouldn't (it would indicate a serious XSS vulnerability).

You can try something similar though, with an no-break-space unicode character.
This is exactly the same thing that he is suggesting with   except I am suggesting you use the actual character itself.

I think you can just copy it from the wiki page, right between the quotes where it says non-breaking space (" ").
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

This route is a bit iffy as well though, sometimes unicode explodes.
You may be better of just accepting the limitations.

Comment: That was a good idea. However if I include the unicode U+00A0 , the plus turns up as &#43;

Comment: Bummer. Unless it supports some kind of forum specific language (Think about the little syntax goodies on SO), you may be stuck with a resume wall-o-text. Typically, they will ask for the PDF as well, if that is the case I wouldn't worry too much.